# How to implement opendrive in android application

Tags: android

I know there's an apk for opendrive in android market but can anyone show me a tutorial or link which shows how to implement opendrive in android application

i have googled it but all opendrive provides still now is there own apk link in googleplay appstore: https://www.opendrive.com/apps/android

please give me a link or a example how to implement that

EDIT: I have completed the login and checking of files in OpenDrivein android but I can't implement the upload and download for it because I can't find any url's for it, does anyone know of the url's required to implement Opendrive in android application?? i have mailed to their support centre also but still no help from there too

any help is appreciable
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following are the features provided by opendrive.. which feature do you want in your application?

1. Upload and preview files
2. Upload new file version
3. Create folders and subfolders
4. Send file to email
5. Store files for offline
6. Access Shared folders
7. Copy link to clipboard
8. Play music and video
9. Keep me logged in
10. Passcode Lock

There is an [API of OpenDrive](https://www.opendrive.com/apps/api). You can use that. They also provide example code, that is in PHP though.

Dropbox, Google Drive, SpiderOak, Ubuntu One and SkyDrive include many other similar options you have in case you want better and more tested API.

[EDIT] Ubuntu One Comes with documentation for Android too https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/ . If that can serve your purpose, go ahead use it.

Comment: i have checked out that link too but i want to implement all these functionality in a android app

and unfortunately im not accustomed to php 


by the way do you know of any links which gives api for spideroak and ubuntu one